# how to convert many points to a multipoint  in postgis

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, gis, geospatial, postgis

I need to convert a table of points where i have those columns (id,the_geom)
to a multipoints?

Why I need to do this? Because I want to create a buffer around each point, and if I work with point i will get one buffer for each point, but what i really nead is on polygone buffer for the whole table. The table countains more than 2000 records.

here is an image illustrating what i need to do (buffering a multi point):

[image]

many thanks

Answer (score 6):

The function you are looking for is ST_Union in the aggregate form:

```
SELECT ST_Multi(ST_Union(the_geom)) FROM myTable;
```

Comment: i am getting an empty colomn as a result

Comment: the same thing. May be it is because i have 2000 points ??? because when i try it with a condition to limit number of points to 10 i get a good answer.

Comment: paco tell me please how would you proceed to create one polygone buffer of a table with more than 2000 points ?

Comment: Maybe ST_Union has some restrictions about the form of the geometries (valid?, intersections allowed?), I can't find any restriction in the docs but you should try with ST_Collect it does the same but with a different method, maybe it works with your data. `SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Multi(ST_Collect(the_geom)),0.01) FROM myTable;`

Answer (score 2):

This might just be a display problem, if you are using pgAdmin III to view the query result. It seems that geometries with a large number of records (e.g. 2000 in this case) won't display in the data output pane.

You could check the result of your query by using:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(the_geom),0.90)) As cc_hull FROM mytable;
```

This should return the concave hull polygon as text in the data output pane.

Answer (score 0):

I think [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_ConvexHull.html) is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom)),0.01) FROM mytable;
```